# Android - Is using dp for font ever ok?

Tags: android, text-size

I know that sp is the preferred one to use for text. I was wondering if it would be better to use dp in some situations. Since sp scales with user preferences, it may become too big. Would it be ok to use dp and try to make it as large as possible without letting the user change it to prevent overlapping, extra lines, or parts being cut off? If not, is there any way to autoscale views to ensure they will not exceed the space I want them to be in?

Comment: It's probably never officially recommended. I've used it occasionally - for example, in an ActionBar with spinner navigation, where I wanted to ensure that the spinner would always be visible beneath the app title.

Answer (score 0):

DP is not any good for text. I do understand your concern with SP and your wish to use DP but you will not get anything close to good by using DP. You will still use SP because it is better for text nearly in every case.

Best,
Mack.